# How to add nodes of a autoscaling group automatically to nginx or HAProxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling

[image]

In the above architecture (source: http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Web_Hosting_Best_Practices.pdf), The application server cluster belong to an autoscaling group. But is load balanced by a software loadbalancer (like nginx or HAProxy). My question is if the how the nodes in autoscaling group registers itself automatically with the loadbalancer(As I understand Elastic loadbalancer has this capability builtinm which may not be case for nginx or HAProxy)

Comment: So you aren't using elastic load balancer and you want to know how to register a new node with your own LB solution?

Comment: Yes, I mean, the above architecture shown in AWS whitepaper, says the same, I want to understand how the node is registered automatically with the loadbalancer when ever the autoscaling happens adding a new node

Answer (score 2):

When you create Autoscaling group in AWS, you connect it with launch configuration which is responsible for launching new instances of the specific image, so each instance is automatically assigned to autoscaling group.

In the next step, you register your load balancer with your autoscaling group, so load balancer can use any of the instances that belongs to the group.
Please check this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-register-lbs-with-asg.html

Zoran

Comment: and I assume this load balance need not be ELB

Comment: It's easiest with ELB, but you don't have to use it. You can use some other load balancers if you wish. Here is an article describing benchmarks of using other load balancers, which you might find useful http://www.rightscale.com/blog/cloud-management-best-practices/benchmarking-load-balancers-cloud

Comment: I don't see how this answers the actual question *at all*.  This is ELB-specific.

Comment: This only answers how to scale the web server, how would you attach the upstream autoscaling group? Thats the real question which was unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great blog post on how to do this using PHP app.

http://www.kloppmagic.ca/auto-scaling-with-haproxy/

Of course you could use other tools like consul and service discovery baked into your image.